# Upload Image Files Temporarily on Client Before Uploading to Server

Tags: javascript, image, html, local-storage

I am working on a project somewhat similar to Wix. Here users can create new pages and then add different elements to those pages. In Phase 1 we are working on 4 elements.

- Text
- Link
- Panels
- Image

All the changes that user makes to these elements are stored in an HTML5 storage if available (else we use cookies). These changes are only updated to db once the user clicks on Save button.

Now I want to give user the live updates on the viewer of the changes that it makes. So when a user gives an image path(local-directory/Url), I want to show him that image in `<img>` tag in the viewer. But I don't want to upload the file to server yet. Is there any way that I can upload the file in HTML5 storage and use it to show image? My colleague suggested that I create a temp directory on user's system and keep the files there. I want to avoid this because if the user exits the project improperly I will not be able to remove my temp folder. So any suggestions or tutorials would be nice.

Regards: Jehanzeb Malik

Comment: check how tinymce achieves this, it will help u, it stores the text as base64 encoded in img tag scr attribute. When user hits submit, the image is uploaded to server and the src attribute value is replaced by the path of the image on the server